# Hive cursor implementation alternative

Tags: sql, hadoop, cursor, hive

I'm trying to implement a script written in sql to hive query, but I'm stuck at cursor implementation, which I cannot find alternative of. I know hive doesnot support cursors, but is there an alternate way (writing a udf or something) so that would match result of the cursor query.

problem: There are two tables, first of which consists field names only of the second table. Using cursor I iterate all the contents of the first table to select values respectively from the second table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PL/HQL, which is build on top of Hive and provides an interface which supports cursor and other stored procedure.

You can start-off with this: http://www.plhql.org/start

Comment: Could you add some content from the link?